# Finder View Options

Tags: finder

In Finder's view options:

- I assume that "Always open in list view" pertains only to the current folder. True?
- I assume that "Use as Defaults" pertains to the icon size, text size, and columns for that type of view—icons, list, columns, or cover flow—and is folder agnostic. True?

  - For example, I set the list view to use the small icon size and 10 point font. Would that propagate across all folders opened in the list view or is that specific to just the current folder?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Use as Defaults" means for all windows, and in your case for all list view windows.